# Do you use ARcore to have 3D object detection and 3D object tracking the opportunity?

Tags: arcore

Do you use ARcore to have 3D object detection and 3D object tracking the opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

Arcore doesnt have object detection as of now. When you talk of object tracking there is a concept called trackables. These trackables are however planes that you detect which the session can store and help better re-localize.

You could train a model with tensor flow and create an app that uses tensorflow for either image classification or object detection and make it work with arcore.